# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel 6 Edit Page

Tags: php, join, html-select, edit, laravel-6

I am unable to find the proper way to resolve this error.

I have tried this code in my **PostController.php** file and **edit()** function

**FileName:** **PostController.php**

```
    {
        $posts = DB::table('categories')
        ->join('posts', 'categories.id', 'posts.category_id')
        ->get();
        return view('post.edit', compact('posts'));
    }
```

Now have a look at **edit.blade.php** file.
I want to retrieve the data from **categories** table from the database into the **edit post page**

**FileName**: **edit.blade.php**

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
                      <option>Select category</option>

                      @foreach($categories as $category)
                      <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }} 
                      </option>
                      @endforeach

                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add code [as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not as images!

Comment: Mr. MrBean Bremen! I have updated the post